# How to modifying the fonts of my document?

Tags: fonts

I would like to use some other fonts than those that appear below on my mwe. How could I do that?

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
                \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                \usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
                \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                \usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}
                \title{A title}
                \begin{document}
                \pagestyle{empty}

                \chapter{A first chapter}
                \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean "additionally"  or "instead" of Alegreya??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) can you help with many of these tons of possibilities.

For each listed font there are basic usage instructions to load it with `pdflatex`. For instance for [Libre Caslon](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/librecaslon/) you will see that are:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
```

Whereas for [Day Roman S](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/dayromans/) are:

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{dayroms}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This web also show for which fonts there are also TTF or OTF versions, so you can use with `xelatex` or `lualatex` in another way. As far I see, usage in that alternative way is not showed except when is the only possible choice, for instance, for [Old Standard](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/oldstandard/):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
```

But it is basically the same method for any other TTF or OTF font, so you can guess the correct usage in most cases, but not all. So for Noto Serif you have only:

```
\usepackage{noto} % for serif only \usepackage[rm]{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

And for `xelatex` you can guess that should be:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
```

However, this works but is not really necessary, since the package `noto` already check the engine and take care of load `fontenc` or `fontspec` accordingly (i.e., `\usepackage{noto}` will work with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`).

Answer (score 2):

There are "tons"  of possibilities ... Here is one:

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\title{A title}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}   
    \chapter{A first chapter}
\end{document}
```